# GCM Id is not getting generated in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

Here, GCM ID should be generated on customer registration. but throwing error.

```
public void sendGCMKey() {
        try {
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

            MyInstanceIDListenerService m = new MyInstanceIDListenerService(this, schoolId);
            m.onTokenRefresh();
            SharedPreferenceSingleton.getInstance().writeStringPreference("isFCMTokenGenerated","YES");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the service class code

```
 @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);      // Newly added 20/9/2017
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String refreshedToken) {
        Log.e("Refreshed Token ::",refreshedToken);
        try {
            SharedPreferenceSingleton.getInstance().init(context);
            SharedPreferenceSingleton.getInstance().writeStringPreference(ApplicationConstants.GCM_ID_KEY, refreshedToken);
            int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
            SharedPreferenceSingleton.getInstance().writeIntPreference(ApplicationConstants.GCM_VERSION_KEY, appVersion);
            SharedPreferenceSingleton.getInstance().init(context);
            String mobileNumber = SharedPreferenceSingleton.getInstance().getStringPreference(ApplicationConstants.MOBILE_KEY);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put(RegistrationContracts.MOBILE_KEY, mobileNumber);
            jsonObject.put(RegistrationContracts.SCHOOL_ID_KEY, schoolId);
            jsonObject.put(BroadcastContract.TYPE_KEY,BroadcastContract.TEACHER_TYPE_KEY_);
            jsonObject.put(RegistrationContracts.GCM_KEY, refreshedToken);
            AsyncWorkerEncrypted asyncGCMWorker = new AsyncWorkerEncrypted(context);
            asyncGCMWorker.delegate =   MyInstanceIDListenerService.this;
            asyncGCMWorker.execute(ServerConnector.SEND_GCM_ID, jsonObject.toString(), RequestConstants.POST_REQUEST, RequestConstants.HEADER_YES, RequestConstants.GCM_SEND_ID);

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It is throwing error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.xxx.cbcbc Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
```

Can anyone help me in figuring out the issue?

Comment: What is that `MyInstanceIDListenerService m = new MyInstanceIDListenerService(this, schoolId);` ? Don't you know, how Service in android is used? Declare it in manifest, and just wait. Token is generated async and may change

Comment: and also, remove that line `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);` everywhere. NEVER call it manually, unless you are extending `Application` class

Comment: I did . Still its not resolving the issue

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time for this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This line was missing in Gradle (app) and should be added at bottom after dependencies.. its described in

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client